# How to safely prevent uploaded file from being run via PHP on any server?

Tags: php, windows, apache

I noticed that it's possible to run a file via PHP even if its extension wasn't `.php`, for example file `test.xyz.php.whatever.zyx` can be still run with PHP even when the extension isn't `.php`! It just happens to have `.php.` in the filename, and that's enough for my Apache to run the PHP script.

I tried (as someone suggested) to put this in a `.htaccess` file on that folder:

```
php_flag engine off
```

But it didn't work on my machine.

The only solutions I know for now are:

- Rename to known file extension, which is not run via PHP, such as `.txt`.
- Remove all dots from the filename, thus making it extensionless.

But I'm still not sure how these solutions would work on other servers than my Windows server (with Apache).

Is there any other solutions which doesn't need the filenames to be renamed in any way?

Comment: renaming files is recommended from a security standpoint. also, check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3499173/my-php-site-was-hacked-by-codes-uploaded-as-image for why you should also add certain commands to your php.ini file

Comment: @SeanCheshire, thanks for the tip. now if i combine it with the findings i told, i bet many more sites will be hackable with it. (too lazy to test myself, also, its illegal;).

Comment: not always illegal: http://www.hackthissite.org/

Comment: From what this tells me you haven't got PHP installed as mod_php?

Comment: @Alfo, and mod_php is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2712825/what-is-mod-php/2712839#2712839 . Edit: i ran phpinfo() and got this `GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1 ` damn! which method of running is the best in means of performance / stability?

Comment: I would say you want `mod_php`, in my experience it sometimes runs faster. If you changed, the method you mentioned above would start working.

Comment: You probably are interested in how apache handles files with multiple extension which might be related to the issue you have and you can control that, too: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/content-negotiation.html

Answer (score 5):

for uploading by users I suggest that you upload a folder in  a layer above the root path
in this case Only You Have Access To upload folder(  In direct addressing)
  and an attacker have not  access to any files in this folder 
Thus  you disable an attacker action  to run malicious file

Answer (score 5):

To be completely secure, you'll need to do a couple of things:

**Set your upload directory above your "public" folder, making it inaccessible from a browser.** This setting is in php.ini (php config file). You'll need to restart Apache for this to take effect. On most Redhat / Fedora / CentOS web servers, this can be:

```
upload_tmp_dir = "/var/tmp/"
```

OR, on my local Windows 7 WAMP install, it is set to:

```
upload_tmp_dir = "c:/wamp/tmp"
```

**Disable scripts from running on that directory (c:/wamp/tmp), in .htaccess:**

```
RemoveHandler .php .phtml .php3
RemoveType .php .phtml .php3
php_flag engine off
```

**In your PHP script, get the uploaded file, filter it based on mimetype (not filetype extension), change the filename, and put it into a secured publicly accessible folder.** In more detail:

- create a whitelist of filetypes, ex: only images (jpeg, png, gif, bmp). This can be done using **mime_content_type()** http://php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php or the newer **finfo_file()** https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php
- choose a new filename, often it's best to use a random MD5 hash based on the original filename + salt + timestamp.
- move it to a public folder, ex: "c:/wamp/www/project_name/public/uploads"

**Preferably use an MVC framework, such as Zend Framework, which includes filetype filtering.**

If you do all of that, you should be secure. Obviously you'll never be 100% safe, since there are countless obscure exploits targeting PHP, MySQL, the command line, etc, particularly on older systems. On larger company webservers (what I work on), they disable everything, and selectively enable only what is required for the project. With a system such as WAMP, they enable everything, to ease local development.

Good practice for working on a professional project is to get a cloud server account with Rackspace or Amazon, and learn how to configure php.ini, and httpd.conf settings, as well as PHP security best practices. In general, do not trust the users input, expect it to be corrupt / malicious / malformed, and in the end you'll be secure.

Answer (score 3):

First of all you need to understand what happens here:

```
test.xyz.php.whatever.zyx
```

Such a file on a webserver on it's own would do nothing. Only added configuration does tell Apache to execute PHP on that file.

So if you remove that added configuration, Apache won't care to find `.php` in there - be it at the very end or part of a *stacked* file-extension.

Check which handler you have set for `php` in your server configuration. Remove it for the upload directory. This then won't resolve any other configuration issues you might have with uploaded files, however PHP files aren't executed by PHP any longer then - which is what you want if I understood you right.

If you've got a problem to find out what this is about, you need to post your PHP configuration in your `httpd.conf` file and associated Apache HTTPD configuration files for your system.

The directive somebody told you for `.htaccess`:

```
php_flag engine off
```

does only work if you're running PHP as an apache SAPI module.

Comment: Something came into my mind now: i think the reason for that to work is to allow such files as `funny.php.lib` to be executed too?

Comment: No, that is not the reason. Also to name PHP files in such a way is awful and bad practice. Such file-names need fixing. The reason why Apache does it are more because of [*Content Negotiation*](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/content-negotiation.html). This is basically all server-configuration, so configure your Apache webserver that way so it does what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `php_flag engine off` you could remove the handler for PHP files using an .htaccess file for a single directory.

In the directory you are disabling PHP in, your .htaccess should include:

```
RemoveHandler .php .phtml .php3 .php4 .php5
RemoveType .php .phtml .php3 .php4 .php5
```

You can likely get away with the below however, depending on which `AddHandler` types you have configured in your default Apache configuration, which, on windows, should be in `C:\Program Files\Apache<version>\conf\httpd.conf`

```
RemoveHandler .php 
RemoveType .php
```

You will also need to ensure that in your main apache configuration file, that the directory containing the .htaccess file is in, is covered by a `Directory` statement which has `AllowOverride FileInfo` set. You may wish to consider `AllowOverride All` if you will be using .htaccess files for other purposes - see [the Apache documentation for AllowOverride](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowoverride) for an explanation of the differences.

Comment: Thats a big list of types to remove, how do i know which types i should list in there? What does the `AllowOverride FileInfo` actually do? and which one would be better `All` or `FileInfo` ?

Comment: Regarding your first question - you should list any types that are registered as handlers for PHP script. This will vary based on your setup. You can check this by examining the main HTTPd (Apache) configuration for existing `AddHandler` lines. Assuming you installed to the standard location, Apache for Windows places this in `C:\Program Files\Apache2.2\conf\httpd.conf`.

Comment: Regarding your second question - AllowOverride controls the types of Apache configuration directives you can override using a .htaccess file for a given directory. For security purposes, you should keep this as restricted as possible in a production environment. I've updated my answer with reference to the differences.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, this is the main reason I no longer upload files to the web server under any circumstances. Instead, I use S3 / Amazon SDK to move the uploaded temp file directly to a bucket on S3 with Private permissions (I use S3, any other CDN will work just as well). If the file needs to be viewed or viewed by a web client, I use a "getter" function of sorts that integrates with the SDK to get the file and display it.

There are just so many uncontrollable variables that come into play whenever you allow any kind of file upload to a web server, it can be difficult to manage permissions, filtering, and even just space. With S3 (or any other CDN), that is all very easy to manage, and all files are effectively quarantined from the server by default.

Comment: this might not directly help with the question but definitely an alternative worth considering.

Answer (score 1):

On Apache you could disable all dynamic handlers for the directory that contains the untrusted files.

```
SetHandler default-handler
```

Comment: I believe this is the winner.. or could there be anything not so good with this one?

Comment: @Kilian It depends... If some script engine is not accessed through a handler (e.g. PHP-FPM via [ProxyPass](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass)), it won't help. To be on the safe side, I'd recommend using a [private folder above the document root](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14171951/2032498) or renaming file extensions by using a whitelist (beware of [Apache's multi extension handling](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_mime.html#multipleext)).

Answer (score 0):

this is not really good answer but hope useful in some special cases ...

you can use mod_rewrite in `.htaccess` file like this :

```
RewriteRule ^(.+).xyz.php.whatever.zyx$ index.php?openfile=$1 [NC,L]
```

and inside your `index.php` file :

```
$file = secure_this_string($_GET['openfile']);
include($file.'.xyz.php.whatever.zyx');  # or some other files
```

remember to see this answer for security reasons [StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8396242/how-do-i-include-a-text-file-in-php-as-php-without-printing-to-the-page)

and in `test.xyz.php.whatever.zyx` file :

```
<?php echo 'hello';
```

now if client requests /test.xyz.php.whatever.zyx file , out put should be 'hello'

Comment: so this works only if the filename is `xyz.php.whatever.zyz` or some other predefined filename?

Comment: every thing can be match with this line : ^(.+).xyz.php.whatever.zyx$ and you can change it to other type like this : ^(.+).txt$

Answer (score 0):

A simple regex would do the job

```
<?php
$a = strtolower($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$replace = array(".php", ".phtml", ".php3", ".php4", ".php5");
$_FILES["file"]["name"] = str_replace($replace, "", $a);
?>
```

This works fine on any server

Comment: currently i just do `str_replace(".", "-", $basename)`, no need to think all the possible extensions.

Answer (score 0):

I could reproduce your issue quite easily on our server. There is a way to fix this, you need to edit /etc/mime.types and comment out lines

```
#application/x-httpd-php                                phtml pht php
#application/x-httpd-php-source                 phps
#application/x-httpd-php3                       php3
#application/x-httpd-php3-preprocessed          php3p
#application/x-httpd-php4                       php4
#application/x-httpd-php5                       php5
```

These lines cause anything with .php in name to be processed.
Once you comment out the entries in mime.types, mod_php config in /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php5.conf has this entry which correctly only processes files **ENDING** with .php

```
<FilesMatch "\.ph(p3?|tml)$">
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

What is **REALLY SCARY** is that this is a default config (Ubuntu 10.04 in our case).

---

**EDIT**

On Windows the mime.types file should be in apache_home/conf/mime.types

Answer (score 0):

The following `.htaccess`-code could work and deny access to files containing "`php`":

```
<FilesMatch "php">
    Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```